# Bayes Linear regression- logarithmic transformation of prior distribution of the variance

Tags: bayesian, variance, least-squares, prior

I have a Bayesian version of a linear regression with 3 covariates. The model is given by
\begin{align*} Y\sim N(\mu,\tau)\end{align*}
\begin{align*} \mu=\alpha + \sum\beta_{i}x_{i}\end{align*}

where $Y=log(Y)$ and $\beta_{i}$ has the following flat priors

\begin{align*} \alpha \sim N(0,0.00001)\end{align*}
\begin{align*} \beta_{1} \sim N(0,0.00001)\end{align*}
\begin{align*} \beta_{2} \sim N(0,0.00001)\end{align*}
\begin{align*} \beta_{3} \sim N(0,0.00001)\end{align*}
\begin{align*}\tau \sim \Gamma(\alpha=0.001,\beta=0.001)\end{align*}

Hence if $\tau$ has a gamma distribution as prior and keeping in mind that $\frac{1}{\tau}$ = $\sigma^{2}$, $\sigma^{2}$ must have an inverse gamma distribution as prior.

1) How do I show that $\sigma^2$ has a inverse gamma distribution as a prior?

2) From the above, how do I derive the prior distribution of $log(\sigma^{2})$?
(Essentially, this question is about using change of variable, it is not related to estimation. We have a random variable $\sigma^{2}$ which has an inverse gamma distribution and we want to find the density function of $log(\sigma^{2})$ which is a function of $\sigma^{2}$).

Comment: Are you sure it is [OLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares) and not just a linear regression..? If yes, how do you use least squares in Bayesian approach?

Comment: I have edited the post to specify linear regression. Thanks

Comment: Ok, however after re-reading your question I don't understand the questions. What do you mean by "showing" the model? In you description you also don't describe the $log(\sigma^2)$ so it is not clear. How do you want to estimate the model? Also consider that the priors you use may not be the best ones for this case (e.g. [Gelman, 2006](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf)).

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to specify that i want to show that $\sigma^{2}$ has inverse Gamma distribution. This is a derivation question. Since the response is logged, the $log(\sigma^{2})$ comes into play I think.

Comment: You are assuming that $\sigma^2$ has an inverse-Gamma distribution, so what do you mean by "showing" ?

Comment: I know that is has an inverse Gamma distribution. This follows because tau has Gamma distribution. The variance $\sigma^{2}$ of the Normal is defined in terms of $\frac{1}{\tau}$. This inverse is called precision and for this reason, the variance must have inverse Gamma. But how do I proof this analytically?

Comment: As you say, there's nothing to prove, this is definition. It is not clear what you mean by "proving".

Comment: If you want to send a notification you have to tag the username like this: @StéphaneLaurent

Comment: About your question, do you mean you start with the pdf of $\tau$, and you want to derive the pdf of $\sigma^2$ ?

Comment: Essentially, the question is about using change of variable, it is not related to estimation. We have a random variable $\sigma^2$ which has an inverse gamma distribution and we want to find the density function of $log(\sigma^2)$ which is a function of $\sigma^2$.